# Why is memory usage of my PC while idling so high?

Tags: memory, performance

I have watched many videos trying to fix the issue and all do for a short time then it goes right back up to 40%.

I am unsure how to fix this issue, and wondering if I should just invest in more RAM. It would not be a problem except when trying to do task on my PC like gaming it goes up to 90% or so which causes many issues in game.

[image: Screenshot of Task Manager, showing memory usage at about 45% of 16 GB]

Comment: If you can please go to processes tab, sort by memory usage, take a screenshot and upload.